# Android, Change Image size in ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

For Android, How can I change the image size in an ImageView in a layout?

My image is `jpeg` format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/stop" 
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

Just change width and height attribute.

Comment: i have a problem in  that : when i am increasing the height attribute, only image view's height is increasing but image's height is not increasing

Comment: You may also want to set **android:scaleType** attribute to make the image scale within the ImageView (**fitXY** in my case)

Answer (score 4):

You can also set Params using LayoutParams

```
ImageView yourImageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageId);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
//width and height of your Image ,if it is inside Relative change the LinearLayout to RelativeLayout.
    yourImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to change the size of an image in an imageView in XML.

1. Scale the image by pulling around the edges of the imageView in the Graphical Layout (this is not really advised since the Graphical Layout sometimes adds undesired properties into the XML).
2. Apply a weight to the imageView (this requires the parent object to have specified a weightSum), causing the image to scale according to the screen size. This seems to be the most reliable way to gauge how your layout will look on many different sized screens.
3. Simply adjust the weight and height in the imageView (as others have mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewId"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" 
    android:layout_width="xxdp"
    android:layout_height="yydp"/>
```

where **xx** is the width in pixels and **yy** is the height in pixels.

*(give integer values as you desire the size to be)*